# Can't load a JSON file into python

Tags: python, json, object, format

I asked in another question for the type of this object, it is a text file coming from a URL.

```
variable = [["1","arbitrary string","another arbitrary string"],
["2","arbitrary string","another arbitrary string"],
["3","arbitrary string","another arbitrary string"],
["4","arbitrary string","another arbitrary string"]];
another_variable = "arbitrary string";
```

I was told it is a JSON object, but when I try json.loads, I get an error saying that "No JSON object could be decoded"

What am I missing please.

Comment: Is this a string?  Can you show us what you're attempting exactly?

Comment: I have a text file coming from a URL, I need to parse this file to extract specific fields from the file :)

Comment: @ammoun What you have there is a python object, not a json string.  I expect that the text file will be a string, so `json.loads` should work then.

Comment: @quamrana json.loads('variable = [["1","arbitrary string","another arbitrary string"],["2","arbitrary string","another arbitrary string"]["3","arbitrary string","another arbitrary string"],["4","arbitrary string","another arbitrary string"]];another_variable = "arbitrary string";')

Still showing errors.

Comment: @ammoun Try using single quotes: `variable = '[["1","arb . . . ring"]]'`  Plus in python you don't need terminal semi-colons.

Comment: @quamrana I can't do anything to the semi colons since they come embedded into the file(string) I need to parse. And I can't add single quotes where you suggested for the same reason.

Comment: This is *not* a JSON object. It seems like a pure Javascript file - you can execute it, but you can't 'deserialize' it.

Comment: Hmm, so you need to parse javascript first?

Comment: @DanielRoseman What do you think the easiest way to parse it then, can I evaluate it? I can safely afford eval, is it the simplest way? I want to load the list or the array into memory and loop through...

Comment: Assuming you definitely trust the content, you could just include it as a script in your page with `<script src="whatever"></script>`, then the variables will be available in the global scope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Daniel Roseman is correct. This is not a JSON string. Just make sure to include commas in between each element of the list (you left one out).

```
variable = [["1","arbitrary string","another arbitrary string"],["2","arbitrary string","another arbitrary string"],["3","arbitrary string","another arbitrary string"],["4","arbitrary string","another arbitrary string"]]

variable
[[u'1', u'arbitrary string', u'another arbitrary string'],
[u'2', u'arbitrary string', u'another arbitrary string'],
[u'3', u'arbitrary string', u'another arbitrary string'],
[u'4', u'arbitrary string', u'another arbitrary string']]

another_variable = "arbitrary string"

another_variable
u'arbitrary string'
```

Comment: note that you were missing a comma in the first assignment:

]["3",

should have been

],["3",

Answer (score 0):

json.loads works on a string. It decodes a JSON encoded string into a Python object. What you have here is a Python object, which you can encode to JSON with json.dumps. Also, there's no variable assignment within JSON. The only thing you can represent is a plain object.

Comment: @ammoun You tried something like this?

        variable = [["1","arbitrary string","another arbitrary string"],
            ["2","arbitrary string","another arbitrary string"],
            ["3","arbitrary string","another arbitrary string"],
            ["4","arbitrary string","another arbitrary string"]];
        another_variable = "arbitrary string";
        print(json.dumps(variable))
        print(json.dumps(another_variable))

Comment: in fact, the text I copied comes from a URL so I can't paste it into my code, unless you know another way.

Comment: I don't quite understand. What is the exact text that comes from a URL?

Answer (score 0):

The string which you get is not JSON (as claimed before), but partially it could be interpreted as JSON (right part of = statement). You could try to write simple parser to extract what is interesant to you. I had played around and got this:

```
import json
json_str = """
variable = [["1","arbitrary string","another arbitrary string"],
["2","arbitrary string","another arbitrary string"],
["3","arbitrary string","another arbitrary string"],
["4","arbitrary string","another arbitrary string"]];
another_variable = "arbitrary string";
"""

json_str_list = [js.strip().split("=")[1] for js in json_str.split(";") if js.strip()]
print("=preprocessed: %r" % json_str_list)
print("=json decoded: %r" % [json.loads(js) for js in json_str_list])
```

output is:

```
=preprocessed: [' [["1","arbitrary string","another arbitrary string"],\n["2","arbitrary string","another arbitrary string"],\n["3","arbitrary string","another arbitrary string"],\n["4","arbitrary string","another arbitrary string"]]', ' "arbitrary string"']

=json decoded: 
 [
 [[u'1', u'arbitrary string', u'another arbitrary string'], 
 [u'2', u'arbitrary string', u'another arbitrary string'], 
 [u'3', u'arbitrary string', u'another arbitrary string'], 
 [u'4', u'arbitrary string', u'another arbitrary string']], 

 u'arbitrary string']
```